# why is this differential limit theorem showing uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sequence-of-function

> > [image]

[link to the capture 1](https://www.cmi.ac.in/%7Evijayr/analysis_2017fall/difflim.pdf)

> > [image]

[This is so called a variant of differentiable limit theorem](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Etolya/limit%20of%20integrals.pdf)

I have no trouble to understand the first capture, but I am stuck on the second capture theorem.
I am pretty sure they have a subtle difference, the first one has $f_n$ uniform convergence as given, whereas the second is to show $f_n$ uniform convergence.

Especially the quota *if $f_n$ converge at some $x_0\in[a,b]$, they converge (uniformly) to a continuously differentiable function and....*

1. what exactly *$f_n$ converge at some $x_0\in[a,b]$* means, is it just $lim_{x\to x_0}f_n(x)=f(x_0)$ and this fixing $x_0$ convergence behavior seems pointwise converges to me.
   [pointwise convergence definition](https://people.math.wisc.edu/%7Eangenent/521.2017s/UniformConvergence.html)
2. what's the point to say something like *some conditons..blablabla...if $f_n$ pointwise converges to $f$ then it is uniform converges..... *?
3. In the second capture proof, I have no idea what that **preceding theorem** is.

please enlighten me on those three questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It means there is *at least one* $x_0\in[a,b]$ for which the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x_0)$ exists. As of yet, there is no concept of "$f$".
2. They are not saying: "if $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, then $f_n$ converges uniformly to $f$". Though, that would *still* be an interesting theorem since we will have shown the extra conditions are strong enough to convert the a priori weaker statement of "pointwise" convergence into an a priori stronger statement of "uniform" convergence. What they actually are saying is this: If $f_n$ converges pointwise *at at least one point*, then $f_n$ converges uniformly **everywhere**. This is a *huuuuge* strengthening, and there is a real point in saying this. We have promoted "pointwise" to "uniform" and we have promoted "somewhere" to "everywhere"
3. The preceding theorem is the "theorem that has come before". Namely, the one at the top of the page. It is applied to the sequence $(f_n')\rightrightarrows g$ :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Regarding your capture, the final inequality, is the first $\leq$ results from Jensen's inequality?

Comment: @LJNG No, not Jensen. $$|I-I_n|=|\int_a^b(f(x)-f_n(x))\,\mathrm{d}x|\le\int_a^b|f(x)-f_n(x)|\,\mathrm{d}x$$Is just a standard inequality, I guess you could call it the integral triangle inequality. It is a property of integrals proven very early on in any course. $$|\int f|\le\int|f|$$